# Method Overloading with Optional Parameter

Tags: c#, overloading

I have a class as follows with two overload method.

```
Class A
{
    public string x(string a, string b)
    {
        return "hello" + a + b;
    }

    public string x(string a, string b, string c = "bye")
    {
        return c + a + b;
    }
}
```

If I call the method `x` from another class with two parameters, then which method is going to execute and why? i.e,

```
string result = new A().x("Fname", "Lname");
```

I've tested this in my console application and the method with 2 parameters execute. Can someone explain this?

Comment: Basically: in that case is completely useless to have the default value since you'll never make use of it...

Comment: I'm surprised that this code doesn't give a compile time error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Use of named and optional arguments affects overload resolution:

> If two candidates are judged to be equally good, preference goes to a
>   candidate that does not have optional parameters for which arguments
>   were omitted in the call.    This is a consequence of a general
>   preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer
>   parameters.

Reference: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx)

---

Implying the above rule method with 2 parameters `string x(string a,string b)` will be called.

**Note:** If both overloaded methods have optional parameters then compiler will give compile-time ambiguity error.

Comment: The compile will give ***a compile time*** ambiguity error :)

Comment: @JerryGoyal Is there a way to call the method with the optional parameter without explicitly passing the parameter?
For example, I want to call the second method with the default value in `string c`. How do I do that?

Comment: @rahul_sann IMO, you cannot. One has to pass the optional parameter if there is already an overloaded function with less parameters. The 2 possible ways in above examples are as  `new A().x("Fname", "Lname", c:"bye")` or `new A().x("Fname", "Lname", c: default)`. I'm sure you dont want that though.

Answer (score 4):

If you call the Method with two Parameters, it uses the Method with two Parameters. If you'd call the one with three, it would use the other.

Answer (score 1):

It will always execute method which **first match with exact no of parameters**, in your case it will execute :

Optional parameter method priority is less then the function with exact no of parameters

```
public string x(string a, string b);
```