# Why hidden overload is compiling at all?

Tags: c#, syntax, overloading, constructor-overloading

I was teaching my colleges to *c#* and, in general, *OOP*, and during one class I was puzzled by this piece of code. Apparently it is correct from syntactic point of view.

```
using System;

namespace ConstructorTest
{
    public class Character
    {
        private readonly string _state;
        public Character(char a)
        {
            _state = "First constructor: " + a;
        }
        public Character(char a, bool uppercase = false)
        {
            _state = "Second constructor: " + (uppercase ? Char.ToUpper(a) : a);
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return _state;
        }

        public static void Print()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First print");
        }

        public static void Print(bool uppercase = false)
        {
            string text = "Second print";
            Console.WriteLine(uppercase ? text.ToUpper() : text);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(new Character('a'));
            Console.WriteLine(new Character('A'));
            Console.WriteLine(new Character('a', true));
            Console.WriteLine(new Character('A', true));
            Console.WriteLine();
            Character.Print();
            Character.Print(true);
        }
    }
}
```

I mean there is no problem to understand which function is going to be called

```
Character.Print(true)
```

But `Character.Print()` has two interpretations

**Output**

```
First constructor: a
First constructor: A
Second constructor: A
Second constructor: A

First print
SECOND PRINT
```

So my question is - what is a point of c# allowing hidden construction or function overload?

Comment: Ive read this a few times, I'm not sure what your question actually is. Feel like elaborating a little bit?

Comment: To clarify, you're asking why `Print()` calls the parameterless method instead of the `Print(Boolean)` overload with the declared default value?

Comment: Having some trouble parsing this - but I believe the question is basically "Why can you have optional arguments?" Basically this allows you to usually ignore a parameters existence and accept the default value; however, if you actually do care about the parameter in some cases, you can specify it. Will often be used for adding parameters needed for very specific use-cases.

Comment: [The rule for overload resolution in cases such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39219244/424129) is that it uses the one without optional arguments. [MSDS says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/named-and-optional-arguments#overload-resolution) **"This is a consequence of a general preference in overload resolution for candidates that have fewer parameters."**.

Comment: @Jamiec, I mean there is no problem to understand which function is going to be called Character.Print(true). But Character.Print() has two interpretations

Comment: Yes, as @Ed said above, there are rules for resolution. See my answer for some historical context.

Comment: @pgs You should have asked that question **in your question** rather than expecting people to parse the code for you. That said, if there's ambiguity, there has to be a rule to resolve the ambiguity -- or else a compiler error. In this case there's a rule. The rule may not be 100% non-arbitrary, but it's consistent with other rules.

Comment: @EdPlunkett, done. I agree.

Comment: Mixing overloads with defaulted parameters is like mixing 16th century Middle English with 21st century English. You can still do it, but how does one interpret you correctly? Default parameters are meant to replace method overloads not augment them.

Comment: @DanRandolph, awesome comparison!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the simple answer to your question is that, in the history of C#, method overloading came before default parameters. So, once upon a time to support a method like `Print` with or without a parameter you would have 2 overloads

```
void Print(){Print(false);}
void Print(bool uppercase){...}
```

Along came default parameters, and you *could* choose to just have one

```
void(bool uppercase = false)
```

But overload still exists for historical reasons, and because you can have more complex overloading functionality than default parameters can provide.

The runtime has rules for method resolution as specified in this QA: [Method Overloading with Optional Parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39219180/method-overloading-with-optional-parameter/39219244#39219244)